# Downvote answer because the author's clarifications in comments are unhelpful

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, down-votes

Sometimes answers lead to discussions, and suddenly the answerer's comments become as much a part of the answer as the original post.  I occasionally see the asker being led down a path that he/she does not want to go (according to me, at least) in the discussion between the asker and the answerer.

Is it acceptable to downvote an answer because I think that the answerer's advice and expansions given in the comments lead to an unhelpful solution?

Comment: If the information in the comments is really part of the answer, it should be edited into the answer.

Comment: If you mean downvote just because of bad behavior in comments the answer is "no". Just flag the comments and move on. Downvote should reflect the state of the post itself, not its comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the answer needs comments to clarify the answer, then probably the answer is incomplete. Imagine how you would vote without the comments. Is it helpful then?

If the answer isn't complete or accurate, the answer should be edited. A downvote could be an indication to do so. It might be better to ask the one posting the answer to update the answer with the relevant information.

If the answer is still clear and valid without the comments, but OP missed to tell some crucial facts, it is maybe not the fault from the one answering. Although the answer might not be useful to OP, downvoting seems to strong to me then.

In all other cases, vote as you deem best. It's yours and yours only.